# User defined aggregation function for spark dataframe (python)

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, udf

I have the below spark dataframe, where id is int and attributes is a list of string

```
id | attributes
1  | ['a','c', 'd']
2  | ['a', 'e']
1  | ['e', 'f']
1  | ['g']
3  | ['a', 'b']
2  | ['e', 'g']
```

I need to perform an aggregation, where the attributes lists for each id are concatenated. The results of the aggregation are:

```
id | concat(attributes)
1  | ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
2  | ['a', 'e', 'e', 'g']
3  | ['a', 'b']
```

Is there a way to achieve this using python?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create a new frame, using reduceByKey:

```
>>> df.show()
+---+----------+
| id|attributes|
+---+----------+
|  1| [a, c, d]|
|  2|    [a, e]|
|  1|    [e, f]|
|  1|       [g]|
|  3|    [a, b]|
|  2|    [e, g]|
+---+----------+

>>> custom_list = df.rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y).collect()
>>> new_df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(custom_list, ["id", "attributes"])
>>> new_df.show()
+---+------------------+
| id|        attributes|
+---+------------------+
|  1|[a, c, d, e, f, g]|
|  2|      [a, e, e, g]|
|  3|            [a, b]|
+---+------------------+
```

> reduceByKey(func, [numTasks]):
>
> When called on a dataset of (K, V)
>   pairs, returns a dataset of (K, V) pairs where the values for each key
>   are aggregated using the given reduce function func, which must be of
>   type (V,V) => V. Like in groupByKey, the number of reduce tasks is
>   configurable through an optional second argument.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, we can skip the collect().